# PDO: Could not find driver php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm having issues connecting to my database on a web host that I have, i'm using the following:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=mysql1.hosting.digiweb.ie;dbname=mydbname';
 $user = 'myusername';
 $password = 'mypassword';
```

According to the website: Host Name mysql1.hosting.digiweb.ie (ip address)

as the title says i'm getting a could not find driver error, am i entering the host incorrectly i tried entering whats above and also the ip address - Thanks!

Edit:

Here's all my code

```
<?php

 $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=';
 $user = '';
 $password = '';

try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
 $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'Database connection failed - ';
 echo $e->getMessage();
 exit;
}


echo 'works';
?>
```

Comment: Could you post the error and the code that you use to connect aswell as your PHP version?

Comment: @BhushanFirake, he is not having a problem connecting.

Comment: @Jeffrey Ohh  ya? but his first line of question talks much the same...

Comment: Please don't post secure data here! web crawlers do crawl these pages. Please remove the username, password from above comment!

Comment: @JohnCody, can you update your question instead of posting a comment?

Comment: @JohnCody Remove your passwords and usernames with XXXXXX or something unrelevent

Comment: @JohnCody, could you post the other required infos editing the question please?

Comment: @JohnCody, where's the PHP version and the complete error message?

Comment: @Jeffrey How do i access those sorry? - just started php this week i suck at it :(

Comment: @JohnCody, the complete error message is the error string you are getting. The php version can be check by creating a page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it and loading it.

Comment: @Jeffrey PHP Version 5.2.3 error: Database connection failed - could not find driver

Answer (score 5):

go to your php.ini file and uncomment this line

```
    extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

and then restart your apache

Comment: I've not got access to those files with my host it just allows me to enable/disable php

Comment: if u are in localhost of course you can browse to apache folder and then go to php.ini file and open it and uncomment this line i gave you

Comment: What worked for me was adding  `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: @echo_Me where is it located? that "php.ini"file ?

Answer (score 3):

Change your extension dir to be absolute in php.ini. I changed it from

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

to

```
extension_dir = "C:/{PATH TO PHP DIRECTORY}/ext"
```

and it worked.

Comment: You save my day

Comment: I'm glad it helped (: